# Please explain this Javascript tutorial

Tags: javascript

I'm a total newbie and I'm confused about this tutorial. I know (at least I think I know) that the functions getDate and get Month and getFullYear are pre-set functions determined by JavaScript.

Why are those preset functions necessary for this tutorial if a new Date (2000,0,1) is being submitted as an argument to formatDate? Does getDate clash somehow with the numbers submitted as an argument?

In function pad, I understand that "number" checks to see whether a number is less than 10 and, if so, adds a zero, but what is the argument submitted to function pad? How does it get the numbers to check?

Can you please take me through (using plain language) this tutorial step by step...thank you in advance

```
function formatDate(date) {
  function pad(number) {
    if (number < 10)
      return "0" + number;
    else
      return number;
  }
  return pad(date.getDate()) + "/" + pad(date.getMonth() + 1) +
             "/" + date.getFullYear();
}
print(formatDate(new Date(2000, 0, 1)));
```

Comment: I couldn't get, in which point you have confused? The purpose of the above function is to format the submitted date to dd/MM/yyyy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function formats and prints the date.

The pad function is to add a "0" (not to add 10 as you noted) in front of a number that is less than 10.

This allows you to print a date in the dd/mm/yyyy format.
Eg. Feb 3, 2011 will be printed as 03/02/2011 instead of 3/2/2011

Within the formatDate function, the last line is return pad(.... 
the "pad" function in the "formatDate" function takes each date part and sends it to the padding function to prepend a "0" to ensure the mm/dd is followed instead of possibly sending a single digit variable - such as 3/2/2011

```
function formatDate(date) { // date is passed here
  function pad(number) {    // note that this function is defined within the outer function
    if (number < 10)
      return "0" + number; // prepend a 0 if number is less than 10
    else
      return number; // if number is greater than 10, no prepending necessary
  }  // the pad function ends here 
  return pad(date.getDate()) + "/" + pad(date.getMonth() + 1) +
             "/" + date.getFullYear(); // note how the pad is used around the "date" and "month" only 
} // the formatDate function ends here
print(formatDate(new Date(2000, 0, 1)));
```

Hope that helps clarify things.

This line:

```
 return pad(date.getDate()) + "/" + pad(date.getMonth() + 1) +
                 "/" + date.getFullYear();
```

gets converted to (assuming a date of 23/2/2011)

```
 return pad(23) + "/" + pad(1 + 1) +  "/" + 2011;
```

This calls pad(23) - and the 23 is substituted into the "number" variable in the pad function. No change is required and 23 is returned.

pad(1+1) = pad(2) - and 2 is substituted into the "number" variable in the pad function. It appends a "0" and returns "02"

So, the final conversion is

```
return 23 + "/" + 02 + "/" + 2011;
```

and it ends up printing "23/02/2011".

Comment: sorry,  I know it adds a zero, that was just a typo. But I don`t know how the function works. Why does it use getDate  get Month and getFullYear if the date is already submitted in the argument. Also, how does "number" know to compare the month and date with 10. Does "number" automatically recognize numbers?

Comment: The last line in the formatDate calls pad(date.getDate())
date.getDate() returns "2"
This "2" is the variable passed into the pad function and is stored in the "number" variable

pad is called twice - once for the month and once for the date. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: thanks for trying but you don`t explain the questions I had in the OP or the comment. re: getDate/getMonth and getFullYear and what is the argument for pad?

Comment: thanks, it helps a bit. can you please explain how the getDate interacts with the last line of the program  print(formatDate(newDate(2000,0,1)));  Doesn`t getDate automatically generate the date, if so, how does that interact with the dates in the last line of the program?

Comment: I added some more clarification - let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: thank you very much. It makes sense. But what is the purpose of the numbers (2000,0,1) in the final line,   print(formatDate(new Date(2000, 0, 1))?   do those numbers get submitted as arguments anywhere? what happens to them? what`s their purpose?

Comment: To instantiate a date, you need to call the "new Date" function - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp - which as you noted is a pre-set function in JS. The numbers are sent in as arguments to this built-in function and is used to create the desired date. This returns a date object. So, it is not really a date string but an object on which you can call methods - such as date.toString() or date.getMonth(), etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tutorial about how to display a date in DD/MM/YYYY format. It creates a date, then submits it to the function `formatDate` which returns it in that format, and then prints it to the screen.

formatDate has an internal function called "pad." This makes sure that there are a sufficient number of zeroes at the beginning of each item. For example, if the day is Jan 1, 2000, then the programmer wants 01/01/2000. `pad` adds the zeroes to the month and day because they're both less than 10. It adds 1 to `getMonth` because months are zero-indexed in Javascript date objects: 0 is January, 1 is February, etc.

`getDate`, `getMonth`, and `getFullYear` are object methods of the `Date` class. If you're new to object-oriented programming, I'd suggest you start by exploring that to understand objects. Roughly, an object is a datatype that also has methods for manipulating that data. `Date` objects have `getDate`, `getMonth`, and `getFullYear` object methods for returning those parts of the date.

This code is fine as is, but if you're trying to do more sophisticated date parsing, you might want to check out the [date.js library](http://www.datejs.com/).

Comment: thanks, it helps a bit. can you please explain how the getDate interacts with the last line of the program print(formatDate(newDate(2000,0,1))); Doesn`t getDate automatically generate the date, if so, how does that interact with the dates in the last line of the program?  note: it was from a tutorial that`s trying to teach me the things you recommend but it`s not explained clearly enough for me, unfortunately:)

Comment: No, `getDate` returns the day of the month, in this case, 1. Confusing, I know--it would be clearer if it were `getDay`--but `getDay` returns the day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

The last line says this:

`print(formatDate(new Date(2000, 0, 1)));`

It has parentheses so you need to read it backwards like so:

```
(2000, 0, 1) // make a list of 3 numbers to pass to a function
Date(2000, 0, 1) // call the Date function
new Date(2000, 0, 1) // since Date is a builtin object, tell it that is is constructing a new object or you risk hard to find bugs
(new Date(2000, 0, 1)) // pass the new Date object to the formatDate function
print(formatDate(new Date(2000, 0, 1))); // pass the result of formatDate, a String object, to the print function
```

You will notice that the formatDate function never sees the three numbers therefore it has to use things like getMonth to decode the parts.